# SynchronizedSet and set operations in Scala

Tags: scala, set, hashset, synchronized

In REPL:

```
import collection.mutable.{ HashSet, SynchronizedSet }

var myPool = new HashSet[String] with SynchronizedSet[String]
myPool += "oh"
myPool += "yes"
myPool = myPool.tail
```

and I get:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[String]
 required: scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[String] with scala.collection.mutable.SynchronizedSet[String]
   myPool = myPool.tail
                   ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that `tail` _will not be synchronised_. It will be a new collection, instantiated without the `SynchronizedSet` trait.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just what the message says, `myPool.tail` has type `HashSet[String]`, and your variable `MyPool` is declared `HashSet[String] with SynchronizedSet[String]`

You just need to declare the type you want to avoid the too precise inferred one.

```
var myPool : HashSet[String] = new HashSet[String] with SynchronizedSet[String]
```

Note that on a mutable set, `tail` is a costly operation and returns you a new Set. That might not be what you want. (Moreover, the spec is mute as to which element will be removed)